# python print board game - Why does the code end even if the board is NOT FULL?

Tags: python, printing

I have this code below as part of a python board game - Why does the code end even if the board is NOT FULL ?

## the drop_piece function code should run until the board is FULL, but the board at end is NOT FULL.

```
import random


ROWS       = 6
COLUMNS    = 7

PIECE_NONE = '  '
PIECE_ONE  = 'x'
PIECE_TWO  = 'o'



# Board Functions
def create_board(rows=ROWS, columns=COLUMNS):
    ''' Creates empty Connect 4 board '''
    board = []

    for row in range(rows):
        board_row = []
        for column in range(columns):
            board_row.append(PIECE_NONE)
        board.append(board_row)

    return board






def print_board( board ):
    ''' Prints Connect 4 board '''
    for row in board:    # like for i in list,  the board has 6 items or rows, 
        print ('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')    # front and end has a '|',  in the middle, for each row which has 7 items, join the 7 items by each '|', now it prints 7 slots.


print("\n---------print:   7 items, join the 7 items by each '|', now it prints 7 slots--------------\n" )
#print_board( create_board( ) )







def drop_piece(board, column, piece):   
    ''' Attempts to drop specified piece into the board at the
    specified column

    If this succeeds, return True, otherwise return False.
    '''

    for row in reversed(board):  # reverse the board
        if row[column] == PIECE_NONE:   # if each row from bottom to top, row[column] blank, drop ball, if not, what about the next one, i.e. second last row, 
            row[column] = piece
            return True    # this code should run until the board is FULL, but the board at last is NOT FULL.

    return False





print("\n---------print while drop_piece( )------------\n" )

import random

Board = create_board()
Turn=0
Players=(PIECE_ONE, PIECE_TWO)

while drop_piece(Board, random.randint(0, COLUMNS - 1), Players[Turn % 2]):   
# while drop_piece( ) is True:
    print_board(Board)
    print()
    Turn += 1
    
    
print ('Board FULL!')
```

below is the last section of the output. The board is not FULL. The drop_piece code should run until the board is full, right? but it did not.

```
|    |    |   |   |   | o |   |
|    |    | x | x |   | o |   |
|    |    | x | x |   | o |   |
|    |    | o | o | x | o | x |
|    |    | o | x | x | x | o |
| o  |    | x | o | o | x | x |

Board FULL!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one column fills up, your code return 'None' which is equivalent to a False in python. I have modified your code to keep track of the column and only return false when all columns are full.

```
import random


ROWS       = 6
COLUMNS    = 7

PIECE_NONE = ' '
PIECE_ONE  = 'x'
PIECE_TWO  = 'o'
FULL_COLUMS = ["has_space"] * COLUMNS # List to keep track of full colums


# Board Functions
def create_board(rows=ROWS, columns=COLUMNS):
    ''' Creates empty Connect 4 board '''
    board = []

    for row in range(rows):
        board_row = []
        for column in range(columns):
            board_row.append(PIECE_NONE)
        board.append(board_row)

    return board






def print_board( board ):
    ''' Prints Connect 4 board '''
    for row in board:    # like for i in list,  the board has 6 items or rows,
        print ('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')    # front and end has a '|',  in the middle, for each row which has 7 items, join the 7 items by each '|', now it prints 7 slots.


print("\n---------print:   7 items, join the 7 items by each '|', now it prints 7 slots--------------\n" )
#print_board( create_board( ) )







def drop_piece(board, column, piece):
    ''' Attempts to drop specified piece into the board at the
    specified column

    If this succeeds, return True, otherwise return False.
    '''

    ''' ************** Debug Notes  ************************
        Your code in this loop will and return None once the given 'column' is full. This is your bug :)
        To correct it, you would need to check if all columns are full, and only then do you return full.
        
        ***There are several ways of doing this. I will use the simplest one. So, I will keep track of every full colums.
        Therefore, every time the for loop is exectuted to completion, I will take the value of 'column' and mark that 
        the column corespoding to that number is full. I will keep doing this until all colums are full.
        To return false, all columns will need to be full. 
    '''
    for row in reversed(board):  # reverse the board
        if row[column] == PIECE_NONE:   # if each row from bottom to top, row[column] blank, drop ball, if not, what about the next one, i.e. second last row,
            row[column] = piece
            return True    # this code should run until the board is FULL, but the board at last is NOT FULL.
    #if we get here, one of the colums if full, so lets mark that
    FULL_COLUMS[column] = "Full"
    return "has_space" in FULL_COLUMS # this will return false only if all colums are full





print("\n---------print while drop_piece( )------------\n" )

import random

Board = create_board()
Turn=0
Players=(PIECE_ONE, PIECE_TWO)

while drop_piece(Board, random.randint(0, COLUMNS - 1), Players[Turn % 2]):
# while drop_piece( ) is True:
    print_board(Board)
    print()
    Turn += 1


print ('Board FULL!')
```

This is the output I get after the modification

```
| o | o | o | x | x | x | o |
| x | o | o | o | o | x | x |
| x | o | x | o | x | o | o |
| o | x | o | o | o | x | x |
| x | o | o | x | x | x | o |
| o | x | o | o | x | x | x |

Board FULL!
```

Answer (score 1):

The drop piece funtion only tests all the rows of the column that is entered with the function, not all rows of all columns. So, when the specified column is full, the drop piece function will return False. In order to test when the whole board is full, you would have to test it using another function like this:

```py
def board_is_not_full():
    for row in board:
        for column in row:
            if row[column] == PIECE_NONE:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: I added the board_is_not_full(Board) condition on top of the while loop, but have this error below.

while board_is_not_full(Board):
    while drop_piece(Board, random.randint(0, COLUMNS - 1), Players[Turn % 2]):   
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e14_7_10_(a)_Connect4_game_drop_piece3.py", line 117, in <module>
    while board_is_not_full(Board):
  File "e14_7_10_(a)_Connect4_game_drop_piece3.py", line 55, in board_is_not_full
    if row[column] == PIECE_NONE:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: changed from row[column] == PIECE_NON to column == PIECE_NON, now it works.  Great.                                                                                                                               
 def board_is_not_full():
    for row in board:
        for column in row:
            if column == PIECE_NONE:
                return True
    return False